# How to remove New Line in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
select 'FILE1' || chr(10) || 'FILE2' from dual
union all
select 'file    ' from dual;
```

OUPUT:

```
FILE1
FILE2

file
```

How to remove this new line character for the above output.
I mean the output should be like:

```
FILE1
FILE2
file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET RECSEP OFF` might be what you're looking for:

```
SQL> select 'FILE1' || chr(10) || 'FILE2' from dual
  2  union all
  3  select 'file    ' from dual;

'FILE1'||CH
-----------
FILE1
FILE2

file

SQL> set recsep off
SQL>
SQL> select 'FILE1' || chr(10) || 'FILE2' from dual
  2  union all
  3  select 'file    ' from dual;

'FILE1'||CH
-----------
FILE1
FILE2
file

SQL>
```